# My select box is being narrowed to two entries when I need to show more

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu, html-select

The problem is that my select box items are being narrowed to 2 items

The selected item and all.

I need it to show all the items for

```
function filterTheData() {
        debugger;
        var selectionFilter = {
            Category: window.selectedCategory,
            Year: window.selectedYear,
            Group: window.selectedSubmenu
        }

    if(isNaN(window.selectedYear)) {
        delete selectionFilter.Year
    }

    if(window.selectedCategory === 'all') {
        delete selectionFilter.Category
    }

    if(window.selectedSubmenu === 'all') {
        delete selectionFilter.Group
    }


    window.filteredData = _.filter(window.data, selectionFilter)
    delete selectionFilter.Year

    window.availableButtonYears = _.uniq(_.map(_.filter(window.data, selectionFilter), "Year"));
    window.availableCategory = _.uniq(_.map(_.filter(window.data, selectionFilter), "Category"));


    window.table.clear();
    window.table.rows.add(window.filteredData);
    window.table.draw();
    redrawButtonToolbar();
    createComboBox();
}



function createComboBox() {
    console.log("inside combo");

    let availableCategory = window.availableButtonYears;
    $('#categorySelectBox option').remove();


    $('#categorySelectBox option').remove();
    let categories = "";

    if((window.selectedSubmenu === "all")&&(window.selectedYear === "all"))
    {
        console.log("1st condition");
        categories = window.data;
    }

    if((window.selectedSubmenu === "all")&&(window.selectedYear !== "all"))
    {
        console.log("2nd condition");
        categories = _.filter(window.filteredData, {
            Year: window.selectedYear
        });
    }

    if((window.selectedSubmenu !== "all")&&(window.selectedYear === "all"))
    {
        console.log("3rd condition");
        categories = _.filter(window.filteredData, {
            Group: window.selectedSubmenu
        });
    }

    if((window.selectedSubmenu !== "all")&&(window.selectedYear !== "all"))
    {
        console.log("4th condition");
        categories = _.filter(window.filteredData, {
            Group: window.selectedSubmenu,
            Year: window.selectedYear
        });
    }

    categories = _.map(categories, 'Category');
    categories = _.uniq(categories);
    console.log(categories);
    categories = _.sortBy(categories)

    $('<option value="all">All</option>').appendTo('#categorySelectBox');
    _.each(categories, function(category) {
        var selected = '';

        var optionElement = $('<option />').val(category).text(category)

        if(category === window.selectedCategory) {
            optionElement.prop('selected', true)
        }
        $(optionElement).appendTo('#categorySelectBox');
    });

}
```

After I select the an item from the select box, the data is filtered to 2 items.

I am sharing this screenshot to illustrate what I mean.
[image]

from console.log

There are 10 items in the list.

```
[object Array]
0 "Snapple"
1 "Family"
2 "General"
3 "Computer"
4 "Company"
5 "Other"
6 "Netflix"
7 "Keyboard"
8 "Mouse"
9 "iPhone"
```

The actual item names have been changed but this is similar.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: What's in `categories` when you use the debugger?

Comment: There are 10 items in the list.

[object Array]
0 "Snapple"
1 "Family"
2 "General"
3 "Computer"
4 "Company"
5 "Other"
6 "Netflix"
7 "Keyboard"
8 "Mouse"
9 "iPhone"

The actual item names have been changed but this is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either specify the size parameter:

```html
<select size="4" multiplie>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

And/or specify a height:

```css
select {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Since it looks like you have a dynamic number of options, using `size` with a value equal to the number of options will probably be your best bet.

If that doesn't work, double-check you don't have CSS from other sources that is limiting the height of the `select`.